# objective c setter method memory management

Tags: objective-c

I have question about allocating and releasing objects:

if I have code like this:

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"bla"];
object.myString = string;
NSLog(@"retain count: %d",[object.myString retainCount]); //gives me 2
[string release];
NSLog(@"retain count: %d",[object.myString retainCount]); //gives me 1
```

Than I have exactly what I want. I need just one reference and I have retain count 1

but

if I use

```
object.myString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"bla"];
```

my property look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *myString;
```

one alloc, and one setter method with retain gives me as retain count 2

If I release the object after resignment than the app crashes. I dont know why?

So , do i have to always create an object with a temporary reference, than assign to real reference and release the temp reference like first code?

or is there any other way?

Comment: You left out details about how you release myString and where the crash occurs, so it's hard to say exactly what is going wrong. Calling something like `[object.myString release]` should be OK in theory, but it is always possible that object.myString isn't returning the original object. Use Global Breakpoints to catch the exception that is causing your app to crash, if you want to find out why. "How To" Instructions to set that up shouldn't be too hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  Generally, this is a common pattern:

```
// create the object, retain count 1
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];

// increment the retain count in the setter
self.myObjectProperty = myObject;

// let go of the object before the end of the current method
[myObject release];
```

You can avoid the release, sort of, by using autorelease pools.  More accurately, you indicate that you want the object to be released soon:

```
MyObject *myObject = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
self.myObjectProperty = myObject;

// all done!
```

With many of the Apple-provided classes, you can use class methods other than alloc/init to get objects that are already autoreleased.  Your example could be rewritten as:

```
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
myObject.myString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"bla"];
```

A final note: `-retainCount` is a blunt object.  Particularly with NSStrings and other built-in classes, it may return results that are quite different from what you expect.  Generally you should avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using objective-c for iphone app development, thats why i generally dont want to use autorelease pool.
When I use apple provided classes, i dont use release it is ok.

I realy want to know
Is the following code ok

object.myString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"bla"];
[object.myString release];

or do I need release once more?

Comment: That sequence is fine but unless you're making a whole lot of strings or your app is otherwise a major memory hog I really wouldn't worry about using autoreleased objects here and there.  Note that there is one more release you should have, in `-[MyObject dealloc]`.  If you have that then you've properly paired your retains and releases.